# How to have a Django model variable relative to another

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I am a Django newbie trying a new project, and I am stuck :(

I have a videos Model:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and I would like to generate a simple link to the video's thumbnail for each video automatically.
I first tried to generate it in the template, but the discovered that you can't use any python in jinja (yes.. I am new to Django), and then tried to put the extra variable directly in the Model, but nothing worked:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

   image_source = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+ str(link.split('=')[1]) +'/maxresdefault.jpg'
```

How could I make this work?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting properties on Django models is one way to go. If you do not need to store this image URL in the database, you could do the following:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def image_source(self):
        return 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+ str(self.link.split('=')[1]) +'/maxresdefault.jpg'
```

If you really need to store this in the database, that's fine too! You could try overriding the save() method for this class, like so:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image_source = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ensure image_source is always updated 
        self.image_source = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+ str(self.link.split('=')[1]) +'/maxresdefault.jpg'

        super(Video, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The property worked out great, thanks! What does the @property change from a regular method?

Comment: You can reference properties on a model just like you would a field - rather than calling a method. (e.g. video.image_source vs. video.image_source()). In practice, properties are generally static and are common for simple data transformations that don't require much (if any) parameterization. Think if you had a field that you stored as a CSV and you wanted to access it as a list instead. You define a property on the model so when you need to access the data, you use the property instead of the raw field.